# How do I use a for loop to create a list of data frames, based off two existing data frames, in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am VERY new to loops. Some of my loops have been successful, others... not so much.

I have some observed data (df_obs) that I'd like to test against my model predictions (df_pred).

MY CURRENT AIM: write a loop which makes a list of data frames, so that can I use this list in future loops assessing model performance. I will probably be back for help with THOSE loops...

YES: I do want a list of data frames. I'm working with 50+ species and have a bunch of tests to run on these values.

MAYBE: I think I want a for() loop, but if a different method is easier e.g. lapply(), I'm open to suggestions.

I've done my best to create a reproducible data set and code that mimics what I am working with:

```
#observed presence (1) and absence (0)
set.seed(733)
df_obs <- data.frame(plot = 1:10,
                    sp1 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                    sp2 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE),
                    sp3 = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE))

#predicted probability of occurrence (ranges from 0 to 1)
set.seed(733)
df_preds <- data.frame(plot = 1:10,
                       sp1 = runif(10, 0, 1),
                       sp2 = runif(10, 0, 1),
                       sp3 = runif(10, 0, 1))

sppcodes <- c("sp1", "sp2", "sp3")

test.eval.list <- vector("list", length = length(sppcodes))
names(test.eval.list) <- sppcodes


for(i in seq_along(sppcodes)){
  sppn <- sppcodes[i]

  plot = df_obs$plot
  obs = df_obs[,sppn]
  pred = df_preds[,sppn]

  df <- data.frame(plot, obs, pred) #produces dataframe as expected

  test.eval.list[sppn] <- df #problem seems to be here, it ends up assigning a vector of numbers...  
}
```

Could someone please help me understand why I am not ending up with a list of data frames, and give a correct way of doing so?

Please note - I know there are areas which could be done in a single line of code, I prefer this way of spreading the code out to understand which parts are/are not working.

Comment: The way Stack Overflow marks a question as solved is by accepting an answer---you need to click the checkmark in the left margin next to the answer. Don't edit your question to say it is solved, just accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a small mistake in `for` loop. You had to use `[[` instead of `[` while accessing the list. You may want to read up `?Extract` if you are interested in different ways of accessing elements.

```
for(i in seq_along(sppcodes)){

   sppn <- sppcodes[i]
   plot = df_obs$plot
   obs = df_obs[,sppn]
   pred = df_preds[,sppn]
   df <- data.frame(plot, obs, pred) 
   test.eval.list[[sppn]] <- df 
}
```

---

However, an alternative is using `Map`

```
Map(cbind.data.frame, plot = list(df_obs$plot),obs=df_obs[-1],pred = df_preds[-1])

#[[1]]
#   plot obs      pred
#1     1   1 0.3266487
#2     2   1 0.3745092
#3     3   0 0.8633161
#4     4   0 0.1970302
#5     5   1 0.3017755
#6     6   0 0.9154151
#7     7   0 0.6193044
#8     8   0 0.4020479
#9     9   1 0.9947362
#10   10   1 0.7975380
#...
#....
```

Comment: You beautiful person, you. Thank you.
It's always the grammar...